# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textencoder' error when upgraded to python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, python-2.7

Currently I have migrated my python2 django project to python 3 & after conversion to py3 I am getting below kind of error for below code.

```
from hubarcode.code128 import Code128Encoder
encoder = Code128Encoder(pur_num, {'is_reliable': False})
```

Trackeback is as below.

> from hubarcode.code128 import Code128Encoder 
>      File "D:\my_project\venv\lib\site-packages\hubarcode\code128__init__.py", line 16, in 
>       from textencoder import TextEncoder
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'textencoder'

I have tried to search for solution online on google but not able to solve it.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like that lib isn't compatible with Python3 as it's not maintained. You can find more info in this issue https://github.com/hudora/huBarcode/issues/23 it's an alternative for Python3: https://github.com/mmulqueen/pyStrich

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to solve issue by using `pyStrich`.

First you need to install `pyStrich` using `pip3 install pyStrich` and after thatn 
What you need to do is just replace `from hubarcode.code128 import Code128Encoder` with 
`from pystrich.code128 import Code128Encoder`.

I hope it may help others who have been facing same kind of problem.

Answer (score 0):

`pip freeze` will show it if you have this module installed in your venv

`pip install textencoder` to resolve problem